# How to get default system padding value?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI but I've created a representable `UITextView`.

I want to set the insets to the system default padding so it matches the rest of the app.

Here is what I'm using right now:

```
UITextView().textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
```

This looks decent but I would really prefer to utilize the default system padding, if possible.

The documentation for `padding()` states the following:

> **length**
>
> The amount to inset this view on each edge. If nil, the amount is the system default amount.

How do I obtain the default system padding `CGFloat` value?

Comment: I suppose that padding is the equivalent SwiftUI of LayoutMargin: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622566-layoutmargins

Answer (score 4):

So, I made a rectangle with width/height as 0 and the default padding on top, then I read the height of the rectangle (which is the size of the default padding) and store it in a bound CGFloat. It also hides itself.

You could then pass that value into your UITextView wrapper.

```
struct Defaults: View {
    @Binding var padding: CGFloat
    @State var isHidden = false
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if !isHidden {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .padding(.top)
                .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Rectangle().onAppear {
                        self.padding = geometry.size.height
                        self.isHidden = true
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}


struct Example: View {
    @State var padding = CGFloat()
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        Defaults(padding: $padding)
        Rectangle().frame(width: padding, height: padding)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact use case, but one possible workaround is using a container stack (e.g `VStack` and `GeometryReader`. Then pass on the width available to the `UIViewRepresentable` and set it as its `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    UIKitLabel(width: geometry.size.width,
                      attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: "Hello"))
                        .fixedSize()
                        .layoutPriority(0)
                }
            }.padding()
```

And then inside the custom component's `makeUIView` method do the following:

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
     let label = UILabel(frame:CGRect.zero)
     label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width
     return label
}
```